# Connect ESP8266 ESP-12 with 2 arduinos

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, esp8266

I understand how to connect one ESP-12 to an Arduino, but it's possible to make the ESP-12 connect to two arduinos? I found a lot of information about the gpio as txd-rdx but not at the inverse.

Is possible to connect pins 21 & 22 to one arduino and 7 & 16 to another one? What condiderations must I have to?

[image]

Comment: You can use softserial and use any io pins to connect the two arduinos via serial.

Comment: What advantage would sharing give you?  Is it worth the hassle?  I can't think of a reason why it isn't possible.